# 2015 Honda Accord - missing console port cover

Tags: honda, accord, part-identification

Can someone please tell me the technical name (and part if possible) of the missing port cover here?  I think the mechanic took it off during an oil change and forgot to put it back

[image]

Is it '33-clip, snap fitting', here?

https://estore.honda.com/honda/parts/view-honda-parts-catalog-detail.asp?m=2015-accord-4-lx-cvt&sn=&b=B++3740&dl=

Update: Here's another view with cap on from other side (stock photo):

[image]

Comment: I could not identify the missing cap, but there are too many item 33s to be the one you require. I see in the difficult-to-view diagram that there are two of these openings, one of which is blocked by the shift lever.

Comment: There isn't one on the other side though; see additional pic attached...

Comment: Those 33s are just clips from underneath, There are those 2 square holes: keyhole shaped openings. The cover plates do not show on the diagram. Is it for reseting the oil change computer? Is the left hand cover still in place. Can you remove it to get another one?

Comment: The new picture shows the missing cover. It might be for the oil change computer.

Comment: Right, I think it is for the oil change computer because they didn't replace it after the oil change.  I'd just like to know the official name for the part so I can try to replace it..

Comment: There isn't one on the left btw..

Comment: Its a cover for the shift interlock i don’t see it in the parts diagram. On a honda the oil change reset is done through the steering wheel controls or the button on the instrument cluster. I find it hard to believe that the mechanic took it off during a routine lof.

Comment: Seems like the shift lock release cover - does this seem right? https://hondaparts.checkeredflag.com/oem-parts/honda-lock-lid-nh167l-graphite-black-83113sv4003zg?c=YT1ob25kYSZvPWFjY29yZC1zZWRhbiZ5PTIwMTUmdD1leGwtdjYmZT02LXNwZWVkLWF1dG9tYXRpYw%3D%3D

Comment: I agree with @dashnick: this is the shift lock release cover. (The same piece is missing on my wife's Accord.) The hondaparts diagrams, however, are useless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I am in the same boat as the OP. While I was vacuuming the car after the wife had been driving it for a few months the vacuum picked it up while I wasnt looking. So I found the diagram and pieced it out.

Honda Part No.:54716-T2A-A51ZA,

Lid *NH587L* (GLOSS ONE BLACK) is Ref No. 12 in the diagram below

[https://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~lid~nh587l~gloss~one~black~54716-t2a-a51za.html](https://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda%7Elid%7Enh587l%7Egloss%7Eone%7Eblack%7E54716-t2a-a51za.html)

[image: Lid NH587L (GLOSS ONE BLACK) is Ref No. 12 in the diagram below]